# php array with a index value of an array

Tags: php

I'm trying to have the $adjective array have a value that is from the $currentCount, but it's giving me an error.

it says syntax error. Thanks!

```
$currentCount = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
$adjectives=["a","b","c","d","e"];

echo "<h1> The $adjectives[$currentCount[0]] ";
```

Comment: This line will help you 

`echo "<h1> The ". $adjectives[$currentCount[0]];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap the PHP part in the string with `{}`. Try this

```
$currentCount = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
$adjectives=["a","b","c","d","e"];

echo "<h1> The {$adjectives[$currentCount[0]]} ";
```

Answer (score 1):

You should separate the string and the array variable with the index value because it's reading the square bracket `[]` as a string.

```
$currentCount = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
$adjectives = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];

echo "<h1> The " . $adjectives[$currentCount[0]];
```